# Creating a JQuery Mobile style list view (without JQM)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to make a list view that looks similar to the list in the link below (but NOT using JQM).
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/#list-formatted

After experimenting with various methods over the past few days (including a bad attempt at duplicating the JQM properties), this is what I currently have:

http://jsfiddle.net/GNnN2/

There are still a number of problems though:

- li border-bottom appears on the top instead of bottom
- at small width, the dot overlaps the text instead of showing ellipses
- the dot (arrow) is not properly vertically centered

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div>
        <span class="label">Richard F. Godwin</span><br/>
        <span class="subtext">Direct Research Representative</span><br/>
        <span class="subtext">Ann Arbor, MI</span>
      </div>
      <img class="icon"></img>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;  /* appears at the top instead of bottom */
}
ul li a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
ul li a div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
ul li a div span.label {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
ul li a div span.subtext {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #067ab4;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    /* always overlaps instead of showing ellipses on short widths */
}
ul li a img {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -webkit_border-radius: 9px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    display: block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 11px;        /* not centered correctly when li has a different height */
    right: 35px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

CSS positioning & styling is mostly new to me.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I've done pretty much wht they've done at jquery.
to center the image i basically just made it a background. And to fix the borders I added
`overflow:hidden;` that's pretty much it.

**Here's a fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/GNnN2/4/

Comment: So much better, thanks!  I need to fix the text/arrow overlap issue eventually but your code handles all the major problems.